# regionprops returning single result

Tags: matlab

I do not understand the function 'regionprops' properly. For example if I create a binary matrix with three different areas, it only gives me a single centerpoint as output:

```
a  = zeros(100,100);
a(1:49,1:49)    = 1;
a(1:25,75:100)  = 1;
a(51:100,51:100)= 1;
spy(a)

regionprops(a,'Centroid')
```

But if I add the line

```
    a=bwmorph(a,'erode',0);
```

which does absolutely nothing, I get three different center points as output, one for each area. Why do they give different outputs and is it really necesarry to add a useless line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input to `regionprops` [should be a `logical` array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_BW). If it's not, then it's [assumed that the input is a *labels* matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#input_argument_L), as such it's processed as if all of the `1` values are part of the *same object*.

You can fix this by explicitly converting it to a  `logical` matrix

```
regionprops(logical(a), 'Centroid')   % or regionprops(a == 1, 'Centroid')
```

The better option may be to make `a` a `logical` to begin with by using `false` rather than `zeros` to construct `a`.

```
a = false(100, 100);
a(1:49,1:49)    = 1;
a(1:25,75:100)  = 1;
a(51:100,51:100)= 1;
```

The reason why the no-op erode causes it to work, is that the output of `bwmorph` is a logical matrix.

Comment: For `false` - +1. I was just about to comment.